# how to install grub on installed ubuntu disk?

Tags: grub2

I have installed ubuntu, and somehow my grub is not detected because my 1st disk has a bad sector, I have tried using this command:

`sudo grub-install /dev/sdb1 --recheck --force-lba`

and it didn't work. It prompted a message like:

`/dev/loop0 does not have any corresponding BIOS drive.`

How to install grub on current running partition?

Comment: anyone please??

Answer (score 1):

Try boot-repair by booting into ubuntu from live USB.

Install boot repair --> For this, open a terminal and do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Run boot-repair -->

```
sudo boot-repair
```

Click on "Recommended repair". Write on a paper the new URL that will appear.

Reboot your PC

Comment: it took long time with dialog "scanning system please wait", is it normally like this?

Answer (score -1):

Normally you install grub to the whole drive ( /dev/sdb ), not a partition on it, but in your case, you seem to be using WUBI, so you can't use grub-install.  My recommendation would be to stop using WUBI and do a real install of Ubuntu, since wubi is no longer supported.